# Unable to render html tags that were returned by the server dynamically

Tags: html, css, reactjs, render

In my React project, I make an API call to the server which returns some HTML that I have to render. Below is the API call result:
[image]

So this `unit_configuration_label` field does not properly render. The styling that I applied to that `b`-tag does not apply. I guess its because the page renders first before I get the results from the server, and then when we get it, it just appends this result as a string, this is what I get on render:
[image]

And I need to append that HTML inside this `span`-tag

```
      <div className="room-types">
        <span>{hotel.unit_configuration_label}</span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML":

```
  const data = "Twin Room with Bath </br><b>Hotel room</b>:2 beds";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}
    />
    </div>
  );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hypatia-ljyb02

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Do you know the reason why that was happening?

Comment: {hotel.unit_configuration_label} is treating your value as string. Using inner html the elements are parsed as such. Also read here for more :https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml